# Writing a commit message with Atom Editor

Tags: git, commit, atom-editor

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

I've done this in order to have atom as the editor, and git does indeed open atom when I do not add a commit message. My problem is that I don't know what to do next? I've tried writing a message on the first line, saving, and then closing, but it doesn't commit at all.

Comment: What platform are you working on? I've just tested on OS X and it works.

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Note: Atom 1.6.0 will have this issue fixed. See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26735294/6309)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update March 2016: [issue 11053](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/11053) has been fixed by [DamienG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5720/damieng), because:

> Existing solution caused Command Prompt to exit and sleep command is not built in to Windows.
>   New solution works by spawning powershell child process that passes it's PID to atom and then waits indefinitely. When atom terminates that process the parent process continues.

Instead of waiting for Atom 1.7, one can immediately replace the `atom.cmd` by [this one](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/resources/win/atom.cmd).

---

Update February 2016: [issue 3074](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3074) just got closed with [PR 9798](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/9798):

> This has been fixed and should be out in **Atom 1.6.0**.

---

Original answer (late 2014)

The `--wait` option does not work for now (Q4 2014,  v0.141.0+) on Windows.

See  [issue 3074](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3074)

```
atom --wait myfile.txt
```

> Immediately terminates, but does continue to open the file. Expected result is to wait until the file is closed in the editor.

Comment: A year later, and it's still broken. :(

Comment: year 2016 with Atom 1.4 and result still same.

Comment: I just fixed this so it should be in the next release - 1.7.  https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/11053  (you could replace your atom.cmd with the one from https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/resources/win/atom.cmd if you want it now!)

Comment: @DamienG Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: For some reason, after I ctrl+s my commit in atom, and ctrl+w out of atom, the git client does not recover from the commit. It hangs as if it is still waiting. This is with the new atom.cmd.

Comment: @Sam Strange, what version of Atom are you using? On which OS? With which version of git?

Comment: @VonC git version 2.7.2 atom 1.60 with modified atom.cmd, windows 10

Comment: @Sam OK, you can either ask a new question, and/or report a bug to atom (https://github.com/atom/atom/issues)

Comment: @Vonc Just reported atom issue. thanks for direction.